# Differentiating between going to home screen after showing browser due to ad or going back to app from browser due to ad

Tags: android, events, ads, android-lifecycle

I've an app that should always start from the initial activity when its icon on home screen is pressed.

I've managed to make this work in every situation by finishing the current activities when the application was going to be exited.

But there's a point in the app where this is not possible unless I ruin user experience a lot, which is if the user opens an ad offered by the app and then either goes to home screen (via home button for example) or press back button to keep on using the app.

In both cases the following events are fired: onAdLeftApplication-> onAdClosed-> on Resume (although as how I understand documentation onAdClosed shouldn't fire in the case of opening the browser, but well... it happens).

With this I find no way to differentiate between the 2 cases, although there might be an event, that would allow to differentiate them-

Think the easiest way to solve this problem is to always force that if the icon is pressed what is fired is never onResume, always onCreate, this way I don't have to worry about the app not starting from beginning for whatever, by default it's going to do that.

But maybe what I'm mentioning is not possible anyway, so maybe some event like the one I'm mentioning might help with this problem. I'll happily listen to any recomendation about that.

Comment: Your scenario will not work in more than just this case. If the user's phone runs low on memory your code wont always be called. Why do you need to force the initial activity everytime?

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin, app can be protected by a password input by the user and I've also designed the app to show just one interstitial ad every time is used, if  just by indirectly exiting the app via a browser the password input is jumped well... that's what I'd call shitty protection, also not to overwhelm the user with ads, I'm just showing one interstitial ad per application use, if the user resumes in the same use he gets a "use without interstitial ad" (although on the other hand in order to do this he'd have to tap one).

Comment: Make all activities extend a base activity. in "onStart" show the pin screen then ad.

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin, thanks, I'll check.